# Magrittr %>% Operator to change the dimensions of a Matrix

Tags: r, dplyr

I am making my baby steps with the `%>%` operator in R. It is extremely useful, but sometimes I get stuck on what must be simple stuff.

Consider the following example:

```
mm<-matrix(nrow=4, ncol=5, seq(20))
dim(mm)<-NULL
```

which I use to flatten a matrix. How can I flatten mm using `%>%`?

Comment: Questions that are only about how R works are generally off topic here. This should be on topic on [SO]. If you wait, we can try to migrate it for you.

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be `c()`:

```
mm %>% c
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a function:

```
set_dim_to_null <- function(mat) {
  dim(mat) <- NULL
  mat
}

mm %>% 
  set_dim_to_null()
```

Or use braces that can act like an anonymous function:

```
mm %>% {
    dim(.) <- NULL
    .
  }
```

Comment: Very useful. I understood better also anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
mm %>% as.numeric
```

also produces the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Magrittr has a few [aliases](http://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/aliases.html) for setters.

`dim` is not among them, but setters in R are really just functions with special names that end in `<-` and return modified objects. So simply doing the following will give you a nicely named function that does what you want:

```
set_dim <- `dim<-`
```

You can either use an alias like this or the plain setter’s name in pipes:

```
mm %>% set_dim(NULL)
mm %>% `dim<-`(NULL)
```